# ISPConfig 3 Cannot login after installation

Tags: ispconfig

I have just finished ISPConfig 3 installation. The problem is that when I try to login at main panel: remote_host:8080, entering admin and admin as user and password the page is reloaded and nothing happens. It won't go to the index.php page. But it also won't say the the login information is incorrect. I have tried wrong information as login and then it will say that the information is invalid.
What could be happening?
Thanks in advance for the help!
Henrique

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/ispconfig-new-install-cant-login-w-default-admin-admin.36391/ ... have you tried googling your issues and trying the results that come back? Have you asked this on the ISPConfig forums? They'd be bette placed to help you than people here

Comment: Hi Martin! I did..... but I couldn't make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete cookies, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and deleting cookies works

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error and did some research.

I could login on `https://$IP:8080/` but not on `https://$DOMAIN:8080/`.

Deleting cookies did not work for me.

The problem is a login-cookie, it sets the ip-adress as "login-domain" and if this doesnt match, login fails without a message/info/error.

[Found here (german)](https://znil.net/index.php?title=ISPConfig_ab_3.1.x_-_Webinterface_als_Subdomain_auf_Port_443_https_einrichten#comment-1416)